# Accessing Firebase using PHP

Tags: php, firebase

How to use Firebase with PHP. I got this url https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php but I have many errors such as DEFAULT_TOKEN. I don't know how to get DEFAULT_TOKEN

Comment: I think the DEFAULT_TOKEN can be gotten from Firebase account

Answer (score 2):

From your Firebase App Dashboard, go to the secrets section and reveal your Firebase Secret Token.  This token is what you use as DEFAULT TOKEN in firebase-php.